# Quill editor not clickable when content is preloaded

Tags: jquery, quill

I am using Quill Editor and Quill Mentions.

```
<div id="standalone-container">
     <div id="editor"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
  const quill = new Quill("#editor", {
  theme: 'snow',
  modules: {
     toolbar: toolbarOptions,
     mention: {
        allowedChars: /^[A-Za-z\séèçàö]*$/,
        mentionDenotationChars: ["@"],
        source: function (searchTerm, renderList, mentionChar) {
           let values;

           if (mentionChar === "@") {
              values = atValues;
           }

           if (searchTerm.length === 0) {
              renderList(values, searchTerm);
           } else {
              const matches = [];
              for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
              if (~values[i].value.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
                 matches.push(values[i]);
              }
              }
              renderList(matches, searchTerm);
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

});

This works well, but now I would like to be able to edit the content which has been posted.
I retrieve that content in Ajax, then fill the editor:

```
  $(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
     var comment_id = $(this).attr("id");
     $.ajax({
        url: "/includes/getContent.php",
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {action: 'edit', id: comment_id},
        success:function(data){
           quill.root.innerHTML = data.contenu;
           $('#comment_id').val(comment_id);
           $('#editor').focus();
        }
     })
  });
```

This works but the #editor div is not clickable, the content can not be modified.